# How to redirect link from list of posts to valid post?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx

Problem is with routing on my page. I fetched some posts from my API and map them in React component. I get a list of posts (with title, description, etc.) Now I have a problem with routing from list to valid post.

I've tried to nest component in `<BrowserRouter>`, and used `<Link to = {'/'+post.id}`. However it applied proper url of page but I can't go to valid post. Next, I tried to Route into component, but it doesn't work.

**In App.js**

```
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Posts posts={currentPosts} foo={foo} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

**In Posts.js**

```
const Posts = ({ posts, foo}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map(post => (
          <div key={post.id}>
              <Link to={"/" + post.id}>
                <Button>Read more</Button>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Have you defined a `Route` for that `url`?

Comment: I've tried: ```<Route path={"/" + post.id} component={Post} />``` However it adds new component into page, not redirecting it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the `postId` in path parameter while defining a route. Try the following. Observe `path` value.

In your `App.js` define a `Route`,

```
<Route path="/:postId" component={Post} />
```

Hope it helps!